# Adding values of rows in F# based in other row value

Tags: f#, addition

This is for F#.

I have a .data file which has 4 rows:
Town, population, municipality, and rural or urban type of town.
I have already parsed the column "population" using Int32.Parse.

My question is, how can I add the population of every row based in the municipality name? This is, there are several towns that belong to the same municipality and want to add these populations that are in the same municipality.

This is the code I have so far, any help is appreciated:

```
open System

let rec convertDataRow(csvLine:string) = 
  let cells = List.ofSeq(csvLine.Split(','))
  match cells with
  | name :: popul :: county :: townorcommune :: _ ->
    let parsedNumber = Int32.Parse(popul)
    (name, parsedNumber, county, townorcommune)
  | _ -> failwith "Incorrect data format!"

let rec processLines (lines) = 
  match lines with
  | [] -> []
  | currentLine :: remaining ->
    let parsedLine = convertDataRow(currentLine)
    let parsedRest = processLines(remaining)
    parsedLine :: parsedRest

open System.IO
let lines = List.ofSeq(File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\townspopulation.data"))

processLines(lines)
```

Answer (score 1):

To provide some guidance.

Use `Seq.groupBy` to sort your data by name then you can add things up.  Something like

```
Seq.groupBy (fun (a,_,_,_) -> a) 
|> Seq.map (Seq.fold (fun (sum,_) (n,a,_,_) -> (sum+a),n) (0,""))
```

Here we use groupBy to get the data sorted by what we want, before using a map and fold to sum the population

Comment: There is an even shorter one-liner for this, but I smell homework.